# How to setup multi-segment text to look like a single sentence in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a line of text that needs to be displayed in UITableViewCell. The text consists of multiple sections coming from the database. Each section has a different color. E.g:

> Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet

Each item comes from the database and is a different color.

I am trying to setup five UITextFields (one for each.)

So far so good.

How do I make it look like a single string to make sure inter-word spacing is same.

Comment: Have you looked at the [NSMutableAttributedString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? You could build out the full string piece by piece, adding the color attributes you need for each section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `NSMutableAttributedString`, you could do it like so:

```
NSArray *words = @[@"Lorem ", @"ipsum ", @"do", @"lar si", @"t amet"];
NSArray *colors = @[[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor blackColor]];

//  Concatenate the list of words
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *word in words)
    [string appendString: word];

//  Add the coloring attributes
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: string] autorelease];

int location = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < words.count; i++) {

    NSString *s = [words objectAtIndex: i];

    [attrString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value: [colors objectAtIndex: i]
                       range: NSMakeRange(location, s.length)];

    location += s.length;
}


UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 21)];
[label setAttributedText: attrString];
[self.view addSubview: label];
[label release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

- UIWebView with formatted HTML Text
- UILabel by measuring the text with [NSString sizeWithFont:] and positioning and sizing the label (would also go with UITextField considering the padding)
- NSMutableAttributedString as mentioned by Jason Barker

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the text fields, you can use the method

```
[yourTextField sizeToFit];
```

This will make the textfields enclose the length of the word.

Afterwards, you can place these text fields one after the other giving enough space in between to look like a normal sentence.

Place the UITextFields in an NSArray (in order).

In the cellForRowatIndexPath delegate method-

```
int x = 0; //or wherever you want the string to start from

for (UITextField *textField in arrTextFields)
{
    textField.frame = CGRectOffset(textField.bounds, x, 0);
    [cell addSubview:textField];
    x += textField.frame.size.width + 2; //Adjust the constant to set spacing
}
```